# Semtex Launcher in Call of Duty Black Ops

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-black-ops

So what's the setup for launching semtex in call of duty: black ops?  Semtex as the lethal and what else?  Is it the china lake secondary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest weapon to a Semtex "launcher" would be the crossbow, as its exploding arrows are powered by semtex charges, blinking green light and all.

The China Lake fires off traditional grenade rounds.